# Редактирование записи БД через сохраненную процедуру (Delphi+FireDAC+MSSQL)

Tags: sql, delphi, sql-server, delphi-xe8, firedac

Имею форму, на форме компонент `FDQuery`. `В FDQuery.SQL.Text` прописана выборка из сохраненки:

```
select * from dbo.GetAccount(:ID)
```

Выбирает нормально, отображается все с помощью DB-Aware-компонент. Через них хочу и редактировать запись. Но просто редактировать с помощью Edit/Post не получается - видимо, не редактируемый набор данных, хотя `CanModify=True`.

Ошибку говорит:

> Параметры функции dbo.GetAccount не были предоставлены.

Чтобы редактировать через Edit/Post бросил на форму `FDUpdateSQL`, познакомил его с `FDQuery`. В `FDUpdateSQL.ModifySQL` прописал сохраненку редактирования:

```
exec dbo.SetAccount(:NEW_ID, ...бла-бла-бла много параметров...)
```

Когда делаю Post выпадает ошибка

> Неправильный синтаксис около конструкции @P1.

Если прописать текст сохраненки-выборки в FDQuery.SQL.Text - то все работает, но это как-то не ООПшненько...

Еще можно совсем отказаться от DB-Aware-компонент, и сделать все на `FDStoredProc`, но тогда придется прописывать overмного полей и параметров типа `Edit.Text := ParamByName('ID')`, `ParamByName('ID') := Edit.Text` и т.д. Чувствуется мне, должен быть более простой и лаконичный способ...

Можно ли, вообще, запись, полученную из сохраненной процедуры, редактировать Edit/Post-ом?

`Delphi XE8`, `FireDAC`, `MSSQL2012`.

Comment: Нельзя редактировать выборку процедуры, точнее редактировать можно, но сохранять в базу - нет. Используйте `view`

Comment: Понятно. Ну, это и будет ответом на мой вопрос. Не найду никак, где Ваше сообщение отметить как ответ.

Comment: *Можно ли, вообще, запись, полученную из сохраненной процедуры, редактировать Edit/Post-ом?* - а это смотря где. В MS Access, например, можно

Comment: ИМХО, MSAccess - достаточно "учебная" субд. Мне, понятное дело, нужно для более серьезных субд - mssql в данном случае. В потенциале - еще firebird.

Comment: Вы не знали, что Access может быть не только в роли СУБД? Почитайте про ADP-проекты, это вовсе не учебный уровень, а вполне себе Enterprise. Там, как раз-таки, данные могут выбираться с помощью хранимой процедуры БД (MS SQL Server) и меняться на клиенте (MS Access) при указании однозначной таблицы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нельзя редактировать выборку процедуры, точнее редактировать можно, но сохранять в базу - нет. Для ваших задач отлично подойдет `view`, с которым вы сможете работать как с полноценной таблицей!